Expo-camera zoom level is not working properly
I am using react-native bare workflow(Android). The reason I am using bare workflow is because I want to use some expo features like the expo camera and want to run some open-cv script(openCV script is in native code) for image processing to process the images.
I think I have found an issue with the expo camera. The initial camera(expo-camera) zoom when the app first loaded is very different from the zoom level I set. In the below code I have set the zoom to 0.1 but when I opened the camera when the app first loaded the camera zoomed in way too much. But when I update the zoom level in the camera from 0.1 to 0.12(0.12 is an arbitrary value I have chosen from 0 to 1) while the app is running, due to the live update the zoom level of the camera suddenly gets updates to the exact zoom level that I changed it into. In this case, the zoom of the camera will be updated to 0.12 which makes the camera zoomed out due to the live update that happened when I changed the react native code when the app was running. I don't know if this is the issue caused by the expo-camera library or if this is just an issue of my code.
<CameraView
    onCameraReady={setCameraReady}
    style={[
        styles.camera,
        { marginTop: imagePadding, marginBottom: imagePadding },
          ]}
    ref={camera}
    ratio={cameraRatio}
    zoom={0.1}
    // autoFocus={"on"}
    // isPinchToZoomEnabled={true}
>

I have left all the code of the camera app that I have used here
camera.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
import { Alert, Modal, Pressable, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { CameraView, useCameraPermissions } from 'expo-camera';
import CategoryGridTile from "../components/CategoryGridTile";
import Category from "../models/category";
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Slider, NativeBaseProvider, Badge } from "native-base";
import RTNMyPicker from 'rtn-my-picker/js/NativeMyPicker';

export const CATEGORIES = [
  new Category(
    "c1",
    "Auto",
    "#DEDBD1",
    "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2226/2226124.png"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c2",
    "Microchip 1",
    "#DECD9D",
    "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8382/8382828.png"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c3",
    "Microchip 2",
    "#DECD9D",
    "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8382/8382828.png"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c4",
    "Microchip 3",
    "#DEDBD1",
    "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2226/2226124.png"
  ),
];

const bulbColorMap = {"Green":"green", "RED":"red", "Blue":"blue", "No LED":"white"};



export default function CamaraWithOverlay({ navigation }) {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);

  const [isCameraVisible, setIsCameraVisible] = useState(false);
  const camera = React.useRef(null);

  const [imagePadding, setImagePadding] = useState(0);
  const [cameraRatio, setCameraRatio] = useState("4:3");
  const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const screenRatio = height / width;
  const [isRatioSet, setIsRatioSet] = useState(false);
  const [isTakingPhotos, setIsTakingPhotos] = useState(false);
  const intervalIdRef = useRef(null);
  const [zoomEnd, setZoomEnd] = useState(0.5);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  const [uriImage, setUriImage] = useState('');
  const [standardImage, setStandardImage] = useState('');
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState('');

  const [IsCameraAligned, setIsCameraAligned] = useState(false);
  const [bulbColor, setBulbColor] = useState("white");
  const [isCameraReady, setIsCameraReady] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCameraStatus() {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    }
    getCameraStatus();
  }, []);

  const prepareRatio = async () => {
    let desiredRatio = "4:3";
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      const ratios = await camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync();
      let distances = {};
      let realRatios = {};
      let minDistance = null;
      for (const ratio of ratios) {
        const parts = ratio.split(":");
        const realRatio = parseInt(parts[0]) / parseInt(parts[1]);
        realRatios[ratio] = realRatio;
        const distance = screenRatio - realRatio;
        distances[ratio] = distance;
        if (minDistance == null) {
          minDistance = ratio;
        } else {
          if (distance >= 0 && distance < distances[minDistance]) {
            minDistance = ratio;
          }
        }
      }
      desiredRatio = minDistance;
      const remainder = Math.floor(
        (height - realRatios[desiredRatio] * width) / 2
      );
      setImagePadding(remainder);
      setCameraRatio(desiredRatio);
      setIsRatioSet(true);
    }
  };

  const setCameraReady = async () => {
    if (!isRatioSet) {
      await prepareRatio();
    }
    setIsCameraReady(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCameraVisible) {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: { display: "none" },
      });
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerShown: true,
        tabBarStyle: undefined,
      });
    }
  }, [isCameraVisible]);

  const checkImageAdjustment = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      try {
        const photo = await camera.current.takePictureAsync({
          base64: true,
        });
        if (photo) {
          console.log("Photo1", photo.base64.slice(0, 60));


          const result2 = await RTNMyPicker?.checkImageAdjustment2(photo.base64);

          if(result2.processedImage){
            console.log('Photo2', result2.processedImage.slice(0,60))
            setUriImage(`data:image/png;base64,${result2.processedImage}`);
            // setUriImage(`data:image/png;base64,${photo.base64}`);
            setStandardImage(result2.processedImage)
          }

          result2.processedImage=""
          console.log(result2)
          // setUriImage(`data:image/png;base64,${photo.base64}`);
          
          setModalVisible(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error taking photo", error);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    const fetchBulbColor = async () => {
      if (currentImage !== "" && standardImage !== "" && IsCameraAligned) {
        const result = await RTNMyPicker?.detectLEDs(
          currentImage,
          standardImage,
          1.2
        );
        setBulbColor(result);
      }
    };

    if (IsCameraAligned) {
      interval = setInterval(async () => {
        if (camera.current) {
          const photo = await camera.current.takePictureAsync({
            base64: true,
          });
          setCurrentImage(photo.base64);
          await fetchBulbColor();
        }
      }, 1000); // Run every 500ms

      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }, 5000); // Stop after 5 seconds
    }

    return () => {
      if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [standardImage, currentImage]);
  
  const takePhoto = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      try {
        const photo = await camera.current.takePictureAsync({
          base64: true,
        });
        if (photo) {
          console.log("Photo", photo.base64.slice(0, 40));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error taking photo", error);
      }
    }
  };

  const startPhotoCaptureSequence = () => {
    if (isTakingPhotos) {
      console.log("Photo capture is already in progress.");
      return;
    }

    setIsTakingPhotos(true);
    setTimer(0);
    takePhoto();

    intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      takePhoto();
      setTimer((prevTimer) => prevTimer + 1);
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (intervalIdRef.current) {
        clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
        intervalIdRef.current = null;
      }
      setIsTakingPhotos(false);
      console.log("Finished taking photos.");
    }, 6000);
  };

  const stopPhotoCaptureSequence = () => {
    if (intervalIdRef.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
      intervalIdRef.current = null;
      setIsTakingPhotos(false);
      console.log("Photo capture stopped.");
    }
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  function renderCategoryItem(itemData) {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        title={itemData.item.title}
        color={itemData.item.color}
        imageUrl={itemData.item.imageUrl}
        OnPress={() => setIsCameraVisible(true)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        {isCameraVisible ? (
          <>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <CameraView
                onCameraReady={setCameraReady}
                style={[
                  styles.camera,
                  { marginTop: imagePadding, marginBottom: imagePadding },
                ]}
                ref={camera}
                ratio={cameraRatio}
                zoom={0.1}
                // autoFocus={"on"}
                // isPinchToZoomEnabled={true}
              >
                <View style={styles.overlay}>
                  <View style={styles.circleMesh}></View>
                  <View style={[styles.squareMesh, styles.topLeftSquare]}></View>
                  <View style={[styles.squareMesh, styles.bottomLeftSquare]}></View>
                  <View style={[styles.squareMesh, styles.bottomRightSquare]}></View>

                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.backButton}
                    onPress={() => setIsCameraVisible(false)}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>Back</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </CameraView>

              {/* <Slider
                w="3/4"
                maxW="300"
                style={styles.slider}
                // defaultValue={0.1}
                value={zoom}
                minValue={0.1}
                maxValue={1}
                accessibilityLabel="hello world"
                step={0.05}
                colorScheme="cyan"
                onChange={ (v) => {
                  setZoom(v);
                }}
                onChangeEnd={(v) => {
                  v && setZoomEnd(v);
                }}
              >
                <Slider.Track>
                  <Slider.FilledTrack />
                </Slider.Track>
                <Slider.Thumb />
              </Slider> */}

              {isTakingPhotos && (
                <>
                  <View style={styles.buttonContainer1}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.captureButton1}
                      onPress={stopPhotoCaptureSequence}
                    >
                      <Ionicons name="close" size={24} color="white" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.timerTextBelowButton}>
                    {`Timer: ${timer}s`}
                  </Text>
                </>
              )}

              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[
                    styles.captureButton,
                    {
                      backgroundColor: isTakingPhotos
                        ? "rgba(255,0,0,1)"
                        : "rgba(40,40,215,1)",
                    },
                  ]}
                  onPress={
                    isTakingPhotos
                      ? stopPhotoCaptureSequence
                      : startPhotoCaptureSequence
                  }
                >
                  <Ionicons
                    name={isTakingPhotos ? "square" : "camera"}
                    size={24}
                    color="white"
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.smallButton}
                onPress={checkImageAdjustment}
              >
                <Ionicons name="scan-circle-outline" size={36} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>

              {IsCameraAligned ? 
              <View style={styles.badgeContainer}>
                <Badge colorScheme="success" alignSelf="center" variant="solid">Proper Camera Alignment</Badge>
                <Ionicons name="bulb-sharp" size={24} color={bulbColor} style={styles.bulbStyle} />
              </View> 
              :
              <View style={styles.badgeContainer}>
                <Badge colorScheme="error" alignSelf="center" variant="solid">Adjust Camera Alignment</Badge>
              </View>}

            </View>
            <Modal
              animationType="slide"
              transparent={true}
              visible={modalVisible}
              onRequestClose={() => {
                Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}>
              <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                <View style={[styles.modalView, {width: width * 0.8, height: height * 0.8}]}>
                  {uriImage==='' ? <Image 
                    source={{uri: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/04/70/29/97/360_F_470299797_UD0eoVMMSUbHCcNJCdv2t8B2g1GVqYgs.jpg'}}
                    style={[styles.image, {width: width * 0.75, height: height * 0.75 * 0.75}]}
                  /> : <Image 
                    source={{uri: uriImage}}
                    style={[styles.image, {width: width * 0.75, height: height * 0.75 * 0.75}]}
                  />}
                  <View style={styles.options}>
                    <Pressable
                      style={[styles.button, styles.buttonCorrect]}
                      onPress={() => {
                        setIsCameraAligned(true);
                        setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                      }}>
                      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>✔</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                    <Pressable
                      style={[styles.button, styles.buttonIncorrect]}
                      onPress={() => {
                        Alert.alert('Adjust the phone camera to proprly observe the microchip');
                        setIsCameraAligned(false);
                        setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                      }}>
                      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>✘</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            </Modal>
          </>
        ) : (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <FlatList
              data={CATEGORIES}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              renderItem={renderCategoryItem}
              numColumns={2}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  camera: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    // flex: 1,
  },
  slider: {
    width: 300,
    height: 40,
    alignSelf: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 120,
  },
  overlay: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 40,
    left: 20,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  backButtonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  circleMesh: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 150,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  squareMesh: {
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "purple",
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  topLeftSquare: {
    top: 210,
    left: -60,
  },
  bottomLeftSquare: {
    bottom: 210,
    left: -60,
  },
  bottomRightSquare: {
    bottom: 210,
    right: -60,
  },
  timerTextBelowButton: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 18,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 45,
    left: "50%",
    transform: [{ translateX: -35 }],
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  captureButton: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: "#ff4242",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  buttonContainer1: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 130,
    left: "50%",
    transform: [{ translateX: -35 }],
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  captureButton1: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  smallButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 55,
    right: 40,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(230, 220, 243, 0.4)",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  image: {
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  options: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '60%',
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
  },
  buttonCorrect: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  buttonIncorrect: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  badgeContainer: {
    top: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingRight: 10, // or use marginLeft on the bulb itself
  },
  bulbStyle: {
    marginLeft: 10, // Space between the badge and the bulb
  },
});


I am trying to get the camera in my app to have a properly defined zoom in the initial load of the app itself(not when the zoom level is changed when updated).
